# How to Loop Over Multiple Data Frames to Create a Multi Tab Excel Output with One Excel File Per Customer in R

Tags: r

I have a few data frames each of which will fill a specific tab using openxlsx.  There are multiple customers in each of the data frames.  In order to automate the generation of the files, I would like to iterate over a customer list and write the appropriate data frame to a predefined tab name and once all of the tabs for that customer are complete, write the entire xlsx file to a drive, name the file based upon the customer name, and then move to the next iteration (customer).  I have set up and attempted to do this using the sample data below:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(openxlsx)

df.1 <- tribble(
  ~customer  ,~period, ~cost1, ~cost2 ,
  'cust1',  '202201', 5, 10,
  'cust1',  '202202', 5, 10,
  'cust1',  '202203', 5, 10,
  'cust1',  '202204', 5, 10,
  'cust2',  '202203', 5, 10,
  'cust2',  '202204', 5, 10,
  'cust2',  '202202', 5, 10,
  'cust3',  '202204', 5, 10,
  
)

df.2 <- tribble(
  ~customer  ,~period, ~cost3,
  'cust1',  '202201', 5,
  'cust1',  '202202', 5,
  'cust1',  '202203', 5,
  'cust1',  '202204', 5,
  'cust2',  '202203', 5,
  'cust3',  '202203', 5,
  'cust3',  '202204', 5,
  'cust4',  '202201', 5,
)

df.1_cust <- df.1 %>% select(customer) %>% distinct()
df.2_cust <- df.2 %>% select(customer) %>% distinct()

cust_list <- df.1_cust %>% 
  rbind(df.2_cust) %>% 
  distinct()
```

My attempt at the iteration Is:

```
tab1_data <- df.1 # the data that will go into tab 1
tab2_data <- df.2  # the data that will go into tab 2


for (i in 1:length(cust_list)) {
wb <- openxlsx::createWorkbook()
openxlsx::addWorksheet(wb, 'tab1')
openxlsx::addWorksheet(wb, 'tab2')

openxlsx::writeData(tab1, startCol = 1, startRow = 1,x = tab1_data[i])
openxlsx::writeData(tab2, startCol = 1, startRow = 1,x = tab2_data[i])

openxlsx::saveWorkbook(wb, overwrite = T)
}
```

Any thoughts on how I can accomplish this?  My intended output in this simple example would be 4 separate xlsx files (1 for each cust), 2 tabs in each xlsx file labeled tab1 and tab2, and the xlsx files named according to the cust in the iteration.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your dataset, I would probably do something like this

```
library(openxlsx)
library(dplyr)
#listing customer names
cust_list <- unique(c(df.1$customer, df.2$customer))
#looping over customer names
for (i in 1:length(cust_list)) {
  #fitler data for tab 1 and tab 2 based on customer name
  tab1_data <- filter(df.1, customer==cust_list[i]) # the data that will go into tab 1
  tab2_data <- filter(df.2, customer==cust_list[i]) # the data that will go into tab 2
  #create workbook
  wb <- createWorkbook()
  #add worksheet
  addWorksheet(wb, 'tab1')
  addWorksheet(wb, 'tab2')
  #fill the worksheets
  writeData(wb, 'tab1', startCol = 1, startRow = 1,x = tab1_data)
  writeData(wb, 'tab2', startCol = 1, startRow = 1,x = tab2_data)
  #write out to excel files
  saveWorkbook(wb, paste0('file_', cust_list[i], '.xlsx'), overwrite = T)
}
```

Comment: Based upon my use case, I was able to make this work the best

Answer (score 1):

Here’s a purrr-based workflow:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(openxlsx)

cust_ids <- union(df.1$customer, df.2$customer)

dfs <- list(tab1 = df.1, tab2 = df.2) %>%
  map(\(df) split(df, df$customer)) %>%
  list_transpose(template = cust_ids, default = tibble()) %>% 
  iwalk(\(df, nm) write.xlsx(df, paste0(nm, ".xlsx")))
```

Peeking at the results:

```
#> read.xlsx("cust3.xlsx", sheet = "tab2")
  customer period cost3
1    cust3 202203     5
2    cust3 202204     5
```

Walkthrough:

1. Put your dataframes into a list with tab names.
2. `split()` each dataframe by `customer`.
3. You now have a list of customer dataframes nested within tabs. Use `purrr::list_transpose()` to change this to a list of tabs nested within customers, filling in missing tabs with the `template` and `default` arguments.
4. Finally, write a workbook for each customer by passing their list of tabs to `openxlsx::write.xlsx()`. No need to fuss with `createWorkbook()`, `addWorksheet()`, etc.

Comment: This is neat.  Just curious would I be able to use the openxlsx formatting options using this purrr-based workflow?  Things such as changing startRow from 1 to 6, or adding a custom header?  Thanks for the reply

Comment: Yup. You can include any of the arguments listed under "Optional Parameters" in [`?write.xlsx`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/openxlsx/versions/4.2.5.2/topics/write.xlsx).